# Routing the React component from the service layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-dom

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am using the service layer to communicate to the web API and centralizing the API call and HTTP error handling.

```
export class HttpClient {

constructor(dispatch: any) {
        this.axios = require('axios');
        this._dispatch = dispatch;
    }

    public Post<T>(apiEndpoint: any, payload: T) {
        return this.axios.post(apiEndpoint, payload)
            .catch((error: any) => {
                this.HandleServerError(error);
            });
    }
}
```

HTTP error handling.

```
HandleServerError(error: any) {
        if (error.response.status == 500) {
            window.location.href = '/Internal-Server-Error';
        } else if (error.response.status == 401) {
            window.location.href = '/Unauthorized';
        }
        else if (error.response.status == 400) {
            window.location.href = '/BadRequest';
        }
        else
            this._dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_HTTP_ERROR', response: error.response.data });
    }
```

I don't want to use **window.location.href** from the HTTP service layer. How can I use React router so that the history is maintained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create `history` object in a separate file and export this object from that file

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

In the `App` component, import the history object and set it as value of `history` prop on `Router` component

```
return (
    <Router history={history}>
       ...        
    </Router>
);
```

Now you can import the history object in any file and use it.

**P.S.** `Router` component is not `BrowserRouter` component imported as `Router`. Its lower level `Router` component which takes a prop named `history`.

for more details, see [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object)

#### Demo:

In this demo, a request is made to jsonplaceholder api to fetch a single todo. If request is successful, todo is displayed. In case of an error, error component is shown using react router history object.

[image: Edit long-darkness-fie19]

Comment: Can you please provide one example.

Comment: It changed the route but didn't load the component.

Comment: When I used the window.location.href = '/BadRequest'; it is working fine. The Routes are defined correctly I believe, there is something wrong can't figure it out. I have "connected-react-router": "6.8.0","react-router": "5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",

Comment: did you pass `history` prop to `Router` component?

Comment: I have pass ConnectedRouter history={history} as you can see in the updated code.

Comment: I was passing the wrong value to the Router, as you said pass history prop to Router component worked. Thanks